# Please select a valid startup item

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I have migrated from Visual Studio 2008 to VS 2017.

I am getting this error when I try to run project with the green play button:

[image]

Obviously I have to select a valid startup item, but there are two pieces of information I need to do that:

1. what are typical valid startup items that I can try to select?
2. How do I select them?

I am a long time developer, but I am new to visual studio so please give me instructions based on terminology I can see on the screen.

Comment: I solution explorer open context menu over project you want to be a startup and chose "Set as startup project". But probably you don't have proper project since of some deprecations. Tell what project types you have in your solution

Comment: I do not have a project in my solution explorer view.  I only have folders.  So that is the clue...  I need to create a project.  How do I do that?

Comment: There is not .sln file.  The closest thing I have is a web.config file.

Comment: Probably you do have it - try to switch between folder view to project view - there is a button on the solution explorer toolbox. if you actually don't have a project then if you were converting a website folder - instead you can try to create an empty solution and just add "Existing website"

Comment: Have you open the project file direct with VS or in VS with open?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

It might be the case that you have opened your project using

```
File->Open->Folder
```

Use the right method to open your project using

```
File->Open->Project/Solution
```

or

```
File->Open->Website
```

Comment: what to do when that folder doesnt have a .sln file?

Comment: @T.Todua use the second instruction which is File->Open->Website.

Comment: There's no .sln file because the project is based on cmake.  There's no website; it's just .cpp and .h files.  This is no help.

Comment: why is this the accepted answer ?  the answer should be this: `File > New > Project From existing code`...

Answer (score 40):

File > New > Project From existing code. Select type of project > Next. Enter project name > Finish.

Answer (score 4):

I went to File > Open > project/Solution and found the ".sln" file. I clicked on it and then pressed open and it worked for me. Just spent ages trying to figure this out!

Regards,

Comment: Charles, you might have a misspelling: should snl be sln?

Answer (score 3):

Open Visual Studio ------------------

1. Click File
2. Click Open
3. Open as Web Sites

Another method

1. Click File
2. Click Open
3. Open as Project

Comment: Hello @iamkanaramyadev.  Welcome to stack overflow. This answer was a copy paste from the accepted answer.  I recommend you improve it and perhaps explain better when each case exists as a way to add value to the question.  If you are unable to do that you might get downvoted and lose reputation.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question after I did **File → Open → Folder** as well. However in my case it's not a website, all I have is a source file. I don't want to create a full solution.

Now that Visual Studio supports CMake (to some degree), easiest is to add a simple CMakeLists.txt file, like this:

```
project (theproject)
add_executable (thetarget source.cpp)
```

As soon as the folder contains this file, **Set as Startup Item** turns up as a menu item in the Solution Explorer!

Answer (score 1):

I just selected open file and selected the sln file on the project and boom it worked.

Comment: Hi Suleiman, I voted you up to show you some new user love but your answer is the same as others so you would typically comment on the existing answer or vote it up.   Keep up the work of contributing; we need more contributors.

Answer (score -3):

The only solution is that or this error:

> please select a valid  startup file is that repair your visual studio

double click on visual studio installer and  then click on the More then repair your visual studio

Comment: This issue arise when visual studio not downloading properly. So the simple solution is that