# How to solve the Visual Studio problem at the execution of a program

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I need to solve an error that says "Please Select a Valid Startup Item" when i try to execute a program in Visual Studio. I am working with C++.

Comment: can we see some screenshot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Please select a valid startup item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47622872/please-select-a-valid-startup-item)

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dou you have the c++ compiler pluing for VS? you can install it from the extensions panel in VS
The file is in a project? try putting it in one.
Are you sure you have a method int main(){reutrn 0;}?

Maybe whit more info i can help you more :)